# How to Uninstall Git for Windows SDK?

Tags: windows, git, uninstallation, msys2, avrdude

Git for Windows SDK apparently uses over 5.25GB of disk space and I have no use for developer kit bloat. Now I want to uninstall but I could not find any instructions online or in documentation. On Windows 7 after install there is no uninstall.exe and no uninstall listing in Programs list. Everything seems to be under the directory:

```
c:\git-sdk-64
```

So I would just delete that directory.

I don't see any additions to the Windows path that seem to relate to the Git for Windows SDK.

My basic goal is just to use AVRdude and AVR Toolchain for Windows under windows 7 as described in the instructions here:

https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J67/5.5

where I need Msys2 with pacman to install AVRdude, and I would install tree command, and I want to use a Linux command environment on Windows and Linux to develop AVR Programming resources in a cross platform manner. Any advice from experience would be appreciated since I don't want to pollute my Windows 7.

EDIT - Using windows file explorer, right click on sdk folder, properties, size shown is 5.49GB on disk. I don't see any links installed in the Program menu and I doubt there are other files installed anywhere else. So I am just going to delete this whole folder.

Answer (score 1):

When first installed, the console prompt a clonning action from the github repository. Furthermore, the path choose has a `.git` folder in it where current status and branches can be seen through command line (with `git status`).

I havent' seen or ask for the code of the executable, as it might link or copy to other paths, but to me it's very probable it just downloads the github repo and compiles some executables (as files are not exactly the same as in the repo).

The only thing to care is the link created to desktop.